# How can I get the value of data attribute from a function in WordPress and put it inside a variable in jquery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a WordPress function that overrides a native WordPress Gallery. I added the 
[tooltipster.js](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) on that function, but I want to get the value of the data-image attribute to get the url and then put it in the tooltipster initialization.

With my code, the tooltip works, but it is not getting the image url.

I have a WordPress code that is inside functions.php like this:

```
<li> <a class="tooltip" data-image="<?php echo $attachment_img_url; ?>"> <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' ); ?></a> </li>
```

and the tooltipster initialization that's inside footer.php:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var imgUrl = $(this).data('image');

     $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
       content: $('<span><img src="' + imgUrl + '" /></span>')
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the tooltipster documentation you can use the method `functionBefore` to run a function before the tooltip displays. The first parameter of this function is `origin` or the element that was hovered over to open the tooltip. Knowing this you can use `origin.data('image')` to get the data of `data-image` and set it to the content of tooltip with `origin.tooltipster('content', origin.data('image'));`.

```
$('.tooltip').tooltipster({
    content: 'Loading...',
    functionBefore: function(origin, continueTooltip) {
        continueTooltip();
        origin.tooltipster('content', origin.data('image'));
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/F33DD/)

Comment: this one ouotputs the right image url but it's printing the url of the image, and not the image. I edited the code a bit but still printing the html code and not the actual image.

`origin.tooltipster('content', '<img src="' + origin.data('image') + '"/>'`

output: <img src="path-to-the-image.jpg">

Comment: I got it, i need to add another option which is 'contentAsHTML: true,'

problem solved. Thanks @adam